# Magento2: How to get product categories on product view page

Tags: magento2, category

I've created a custom module and in that created a block to get current categories on product view page. I've added that block via layout xml of module. 
I've used `$this->_registry->registry('current_category')` to get current categories of product on product view page.
But in my phtml file it's not rendering the categories.

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev Yes, I've created block and phtml file in my custom module and using $this->_registry->registry('current_category'); to get current category. Its working fine on category page however product page shows server not found if this block called on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add code in your block file

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Block;
class Blockname extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

}
?>
```

Layout file code

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main"> <block class="Companyname\Modulename\Block\Categoryimage" name="header.product.category.image" template="Companyname_Modulename::product/view/categoryimage‌​.phtml" before="-" /> </referenceContainer>
```

Add below code in phtml file.

```
<?php if ($currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory()): ?>
    <div class="detail-category-name">
        <a href="<?php echo $currentCategory->getUrl(); ?>" >
            <?php echo $currentCategory->getName(); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: it is better to flag the question duplicate then posting the same answer.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working on product page. Its working on category page only.

Comment: I have tested and working on product page. add your layout xml code.

Comment: <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="Companyname\Modulename\Block\Categoryimage" name="header.product.category.image" template="Companyname_Modulename::product/view/categoryimage.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: See my updated answer for layout code.

Comment: I see that you just changed the container name from "Content" to "product.info.main".

Comment: Yes, have you try that changes ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no category available in registry on product view page because its a product page and any product may have many categories.

Instead of that you can get the category id's from product object and perform your logic with that.

Comment: do not use object manager directly. This is a very bad practice.